# Adding a small touch-screen monitor to Vista-64 bits, which already has 2 monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

In [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReviewMimoMonitorsIMoPivot.aspx), he mentions a small [Mimo monitor](http://www.mimomonitors.com/), which apparently works on the USB port, thus I can easily use it to connect to my current computer, which already has two monitors connected. What for? Well, mostly because I'm developing software and it would allow me to see what my application looks like on a smaller monitor.

But now I'm curious about other reviews, and I wonder if other superusers have the same or similar devices as a third monitor, on USB. It seems to me that it could mess up Vista a bit whenever I disconnect it from the USB port or that it takes a lot of power. It's a nice wannahave thingie, but is it really practical or will it just mess up my whole Windows system?

So, is anyone willing to post a review here? (Good or bad, doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a mimo monitor and i love it, well worth the money

Good - 
Compact and portable; plug and play; great for applications that don't require lots of space or high resolutions.

Bad - 
Screen flickers a little; USB port is obscure; could be brighter;

Answer (score 0):

I have one too.  I don't notice the flicker after it's been on for a while.  It's bright enough for what I use it for.

I actually have three mimo monitors.

I've written a review on the homeseer forums found at http://board.homeseer.com/showthread.php?t=136421&highlight=mimo

It's a pretty neat concept using it as the main monitor on a VM Machine.